# How to construct msearch API query with aggregations for Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

Elasticsearch [documentation](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) describes a way to build a simple query body for msearch API query. But if you use aggregations this no longer works either using curl or any version of elasticsearch-py library.
Github corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/207).
Example query:

```
{ 
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
    "filter": { "term": {"applicationType":"myapptype"} },
    "query": {"match": {"search_key": "my_key_value"}}
    }
  },
  "aggs": {"client": {"terms": {"field": "client"}}},
  "size": 0
}
```

Python code:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
es.msearch(body=[
   {"index": "index20150315"},
   {"query": {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {'applicationType': 'myapptype'}}, 'query': {'match': {'search_key': 'my_key_value'}}}}, 'aggs': {'client': {'terms': {'field': 'client'}}}, 'size': 0}
```

])

The output is as follows:

```
{u'responses': [{u'error': u'SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[BRYrrx8dR4i-ukxlXbuNEw][index20150315][1]: RemoteTransportException[[i-1f30c5fb][inet[/10.101.2.234:9300]][search/phase/query]]; nested: SearchParseException[[index20150315][1]: query[filtered(search_key:my_key_value)->cache(applicationType:myapptype)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"term": {"applicationType": "myapptype"}}, "query": {"match": {"search_key": "my_key_value"}}}, "aggs": {"client": {"terms": {"field": "client"}}}, "size": 0}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "aggs"]; }{[BRYrrx8dR4i-ukxlXbuNEw][index20150315][2]: RemoteTransportException[[i-1f30c5fb][inet[/10.101.2.234:9300]][search/phase/query]]; nested: SearchParseException[[index20150315][2]: query[filtered(search_key:my_key_value)->cache(applicationType:myapptype)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"term": {"applicationType": "myapptype"}}, "query": {"match": {"search_key": "my_key_value"}}}, "aggs": {"client": {"terms": {"field": "client"}}}, "size": 0}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "aggs"]; }{[No9GT_PtQh6XoOvfz5uTmw][index20150315][0]: RemoteTransportException[[i-1d30c5f9][inet[/10.101.2.237:9300]][search/phase/query]]; nested: SearchParseException[[index20150315][0]: query[filtered(search_key:my_key_value)->cache(applicationType:myapptype)],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query": {"filtered": {"filter": {"term": {"applicationType": "myapptype"}}, "query": {"match": {"search_key": "my_key_value"}}}, "aggs": {"client": {"terms": {"field": "client"}}}, "size": 0}}]]]; nested: ElasticsearchParseException[Expected field name but got START_OBJECT "aggs"]; }]'}]}
```

Has anyone managed to make msearch API work with the queries that contain aggregations?

Answer (score 1):

In fact everything works, it was a wrong query I used in the github ticket (the one posted above is correct).
So, the command would be the following:

```
es = Elasticsearch()
es.msearch(body=[
   {"index": "index20150315"},
   {'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {'applicationType': 'myapptype'}}, 'query': {'match': {'search_key': 'my_key_value1'}}}}, 'aggs': {'client': {'terms': {'field': 'client'}}}, 'size': 0},
   {}, {'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {'applicationType': 'myapptype'}}, 'query': {'match': {'search_key': 'my_key_value2'}}}}, 'aggs': {'client': {'terms': {'field': 'client'}}}, 'size': 0}])
```

Doing the same with curl is also fine.
Btw, [elasticsearch-py](https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html?highlight=msearch#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.msearch) documentation tells that you need newlines in body but it works ok  as an ordinary list of [index1, query1, index2, query2].